# How to prevent SQL Injection in ASP .NET Core MVC application

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

There I'm creating an ASP.NET Core MVC application. In that app I use several actions to access the database with using Entity Framework. I want to know how to resist an injection attack for the app. Can I prevent SQL injection with only using Entity Framework or not?

Here some queries I used in my controller.

SELECT queries

```
var AssignmentDetails = (from s in _db.SubmissionLinks
                         join a in _db.Assignments on s.AssignmentID equals a.AssignmentID
                         join p in _db.Projects on a.ProjectID equals p.ID
                         join s2 in _db.SystemUsers on p.SystemUserFK equals s2.ID
                         select new AssignmentDetails()
                                    {
                                         SubmissionlinkID = s.SubmissionLinkID,
                                         SubmissionlinkName = s.SubmissionName,
                                         ProjectID = p.ID,
                                         ProjectName = p.ProjectName,
                                         Deadline = s.Deadline,
                                         Userid=s2.ID,
                                         Assignmentid=a.AssignmentID
                                    }).ToList();

var CookieValue = Request.Cookies["userId"];
var systemUsers = _db.SystemUsers.First(s => s.Email == CookieValue);
```

INSERT query

```
public IActionResult createAssignment(int id, string AssignmentName, string Description)
{
    Assignment assignment = new Assignment();
    assignment.AssignmentName = AssignmentName;
    assignment.Description = Description;
    assignment.ProjectID = id;

    _db.Assignments.Add(assignment);
    _db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Project_View",new { id=id});
}
```

UPDATE query

```
SystemUser user = _db.SystemUsers.First(s => s.ID == id);
user.Firstname = firstname;
user.Lastname = lastname;
user.Email = email;
user.ContactNumber = contactnumber;

_db.SystemUsers.Update(user);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

I want to know if I querying like this can prevent SQL injection?

Comment: This isn't vulnerable to SQL Injection. But more importantly: you need to understand what the attack is and what the mitigations are instead of asking if a specific piece of code is vulnerable.

Comment: seems you're using entity framework, and not concatenating sql strings, so basically can prevent.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/security-considerations

Comment: I got it @mason I will refer more about the problem before ask a question again. thank you